# Redis Pipeline using spring data redis reactive

Tags: java, lettuce, spring-data-redis-reactive

Pipeline support is available on RedisTemplate (RedisTemplate.executePipelined) But I couldn't find any equivalent option in ReactiveRedisTemplate to use pipeline or batch operations.

Kindly direct me to the right API or any alternative approaches.

**spring-data-redis:2.7.5 (with lettuce)**