# Is Spring Data Redis Reactive capable of pipelining

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-redis-reactive

I've seen [previous unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74485008/15768984) and I still don't know whether it's possible. Spring Data Redis (non-reactive) has `executePipelined` but is there a reactive equivalent? Specifically, are `executeInSession` or just `execute` capable of pipelining commands?